Cross database reference in Visual Studio DACPAC solution
I'm trying to update a target server using the Schema Compare feature in Visual Studio 2019. Upon checking the sys.servers table, I can see the linked server and confirmed that I can run queries against it without any issues. However, I'm unable to update the target server in my DacPac and this is the error I'm getting.

Could not find server 'servername' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

I've tried adding a database reference to the database it's expecting and building the project solution without any success. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this. Thanks!
